# Writing in notepad with keyboard application

Tags: c#, winforms

Keyboard simulator ،  Like Like On-Screen Keyboard

how to make Like  "On-Screen Keyboard " ?

Comment: pleeease, help us out with at least 1 complete sentance to go on...

Answer (score 1):

In old win 32 API there was a `sendKeys()` method like API. when user clicks your form, then your form is active and has focus while he has activated the desired control for writing just before giving focus to yours. One solution is monitoring focus changes on controls and when user presses keyboard on your form, you can `sendKeys()` to appropriate window handle. I don't know what's the real name of that method and it's equivalent ic .NET but it should not be hard to find out. Stick to design.

[edited]
here it is :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx